# Adding custom error messages in "anyOf" JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, jsonschema2pojo

I'm looking to add custom error messages to my JSON Schema on a bad validation in an "allOf". I have this which works (on a "not"):

```
"not": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "required": ["prop1"],
        "errorMessage": "Property 'prop1' is not allowed"
      },
      {
        "required": ["prop2"],
        "errorMessage": "Property 'prop2' is not allowed"
      }
    ]
}
```

And I get: `"[$.content[0] should not be valid to the schema...<standard error message>..., Property 'prop1' is not allowed.`

Great that works.

I'm trying to validate the max items of an array:

```
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "required": [
      "x"
    ]
  }
},
"then": {
   properties": {
      "actions": {
        "maxItems": 2,
        "errorMessage": "you can't have more than 3 items in the array if x is true."
      }
   }
},
"else": {
  "properties": {
      "actions": {
        "maxItems": 3,
        "errorMessage": "you can't have more than 2 items in the array if x is false."
      }
   }
}
```

The message I get upon validation failure:

`[$.content[0].actions: there must be a maximum of 3 items in the array]`

and

`[$.content[0].actions: there must be a maximum of 2 items in the array]`.

I'm not looking to do said validation, this is just an example. I want the error message to also include: `you can't have more than 2 items in the array if x is false.`. Is this possible? I've tried several different things and it only seems to be possible when a `"not"` is involved like in the first code block. It seems that this is possible to do in the actual definition of the object declaration, but I need to do it in an "allOf".

Relevant POM versions:

```
<json-schema-validator.version>1.0.52</json-schema-validator.version>
<jsonschema2pojo.version>1.0.2</jsonschema2pojo.version>
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a (hacky) workaround. If you add 2 "nots" you can utilise the  "errorMessage" parameter and 1 not will negate the other:

```
                "properties": {
                  "actions": {
                    "not": {
                      "not": {
                        "maxItems": 3,
                        "errorMessage": "You cannot have more than 3 items in the actions object for Line messaging."
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/doc/cust-msg.md), it looks this implementation supports a `message` keyword that contains the messages per keyword.  It doesn't really give much, though.  I can't tell if it supports templating or not.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 3
    }
  },
  "message": {                                  // this is the bit you want
    "maxItems" : "MaxItem must be 3 only",
    "type" : "Invalid type"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is one of the things I tried, I probably should have given some examples when I said "I've tried several different things" but thats what I got from the docs too. Also, I would need 2 separate messages depending on certain params i.e. "MaxItem must be 3" or "MaxItem must be 2". I'll give it another shot anyway, thanks.